# Why does the property become null when passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, types

I have a class `A` from which `B` inherits.
`A` has a property called `Data` which is a class that contains some data. There is also `BData` that again inherits from `data`.

In other words:

```
class A
{
    public Data data;
}
class B : A
{
    public new BData data;
}

class Data
{
    public string id = "something";
}
class BData : Data
{
    public new string id = "something else";
}
```

Now, I use a method to read the data from any class and do some logic based on the data.

```
public bool ReadData<T>(T element) where T : A
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Element: {element}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Element ID: {element.data.id}");
    //do some logic
}
```

I make a test element for `A` and `B` and I pass it to the method like so:

```
A a = new A();
a.data = new Data();
B b = new B();
b.data = new BData();
ReadData<A>(A);
ReadData<B>(b);
```

The output I get is this:

> Element: A
> Element ID: something
> Element: B
> Element ID:

I can not understand why when I pass the second object, it has a null property. I suspect it might have something to do with the different types (need casting from `B` to `A`? is it because I'm hiding `Data` with `BData`?) but I can not figure it out. Am I missing something?

What causes this to happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```cs
class B : A
{
    public new BData data;
}
```

doesn't make the old `data` field in

```cs
class A
{
    public Data data;
}
```

class disappear. It doesn't replace it, it simply hides it. Then

```cs
public bool ReadData<T>(T element) where T : A
```

treats every object as `A`. In particular when you initialize `B` then its `public Data data` field (of the base `A` class) is not initialized and hence stays null. Then even though you pass `B`, it actually tries to access its `data` field of `A` class.

The behaviour is easier to understand if you change the `B` to

```cs
class B : A
{
    public BData data2;
}
```

The moral of this story is: `new` keyword is dangerous, avoid it.

---

Here's how you can achieve what you want with properties instead of fields. Something like this should work:

```cs
class A
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public new BData data {
        get {
            return (BData)base.data;
        }
        set {
            base.data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But I encourage you to use a common interface for both `B` and `A` instead of such tricks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I suspected it had something to do with that keyword but I did not know how to confirm it... Is there an alternative keyword that would allow me to do the same thing without causing this problematic behavior?

Comment: But you still use `new` to hide the base class member in your property solution. You can also pick a free name (other than `data`), then `new` is not needed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, I agree that `new` is unneeded, and can potentially lead to weird, not-so-obvious behaviour. Still wanted to show how we can achieve what OP wants.